# Object doesn't support property or method error in VBA For each loop

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying to debug the following code for a class. For the life of me I can't seem to see what is wrong with the for each statement.

```
Public Sub PrintWorksheets1()
   'declare variables and assign address to object variable
    Dim intPrint As Integer, wkbHours As Workbook, shtCurrent As Worksheets
    Set wkbHours = Application.Workbooks("T9-EX-E9D.xls")
    'ask user if he or she wants to print the worksheet
For Each shtCurrent In wkbHours
    intPrint = _
        MsgBox(prompt:="Print " & shtCurrent.Name & "?", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbExclamation)
    If intPrint = vbYes Then        'if user wants to print
        shtCurrent.PrintPreview
    End If
Next shtCurrent
End Sub
```

I have tried setting shtCurrent to the active sheet and just worksheet(s). Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code: you were almost there but you need to loop through the workbook worksheets...

```
Public Sub PrintWorksheets1()
   'declare variables and assign address to object variable
    Dim intPrint As Integer, shtCurrent As Worksheet
    Dim wkbHours As Workbook: Set wkbHours = Workbooks("T9-EX-E9D.xls")
    'ask user if he or she wants to print the worksheet
    For Each shtCurrent In wkbHours.Worksheets
        intPrint = MsgBox(prompt:="Print " & shtCurrent.Name & "?", Buttons:=vbYesNo + vbExclamation)
        'if user wants to print
        If intPrint = vbYes Then shtCurrent.PrintPreview
    Next shtCurrent
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I see that it was necessary to drill down in the for each statement to the worksheets level rather than just the workbook level.